# Are the following two snippets doing the same thing?

Tags: php

Is the following:

```
$variable = $variable = $variable = $variable = '';
```

The same as:

```
$variable = ''; 
$variable = '';
$variable = '';
$variable = '';
```

Is the first example a more compact way to achieve the same result or is something else happening?

Comment: do you mean something like: $variable1 = $variable2 = $variable3 = $variable4 = '';

Comment: Have you read the documentation of the [assignment operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php)? The answer to your question is explained in the second paragraph (and there is an example under it).

Comment: Anytime this happens to me it's caused by copy-pasting a varible for use elsewhere, like `$new = $old = "Example";` usually I just forgot to remove `$old =` from the code I'm copying. I'm not sure this has a use for being done on purpose.

Comment: Technically speaking; the first 3 are overwritten, (edit) given what you posted that is.

Comment: I just don't know what you're trying to do here really, so I'm voting to close as being unclear.

Comment: @GratusD. Yes,sorry, that's what I mean. Different variables..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these achieve exactly the same result. After running either of those code blocks, you will have one variable `$variable` set to an empty string (`''`).

It's pointless to reassign the same variable repeatedly, but it works the same way even if you use multiple different variables. For example (from the comments)

```
$variable1 = $variable2 = $variable3 = $variable4 = '';
```

will result in all of those different variables being set to the same value. The reason this works is that an assignment expression evaluates to the assigned value. So the first code block you showed is evaluated something like this:

```
$variable = ($variable = ($variable = ($variable = '')));
```

Where each `$variable = ...` evaluates the right-hand side of the assignment operator first, then assigns that value to the left-hand side. The final `$variable = ''` expression evaluates to `''` which fills all the variables in the assignment chain from right to left.

While it is a more compact way to achieve the same result, the benefit of that is questionable, because many people would see that as reducing the readability of the code.